# send email from MVC 4 ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I am trying to setup simple but complete ASP.NET MVC 4 web app, where I can send email to specific address, I configure the web.config file for SMPT settings and code in controller call, but I am getting error message "The SMTP host was not specified"

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="myEmail@hotmail.co.uk">
    <network host="smtp.live.com" port="25" userName="myEmail@hotmail.co.uk" password="myPassword" defaultCredentials="true"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

### in controller class

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add("yourEmail@hotmail.co.uk");
mailMessage.Subject = "testing 2 ";
mailMessage.Body = "Hello Mr. Aderson";
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;

var smptClient = new SmtpClient { EnableSsl = false };

smptClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Best Idea to use SMTP mail functionality in .NET + MVC/ASP is this open source codeplex library:

http://higlabo.codeplex.com/

Especially since the default-delivered components in .NET framework does fully support all types of SSL/TSL etc. (implicit/explicit mode as keyword here)

http://higlabo.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look you haven't set up the "From" property.

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add("yourEmail@hotmail.co.uk");
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("myEmail@hotmail.co.uk");
mailMessage.Subject = "testing 2 ";
mailMessage.Body = "Hello Mr. Aderson";
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

do some thing like this

```
SmtpClient smtp = new  SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[EFloOnline.Model.Constants.smtp], Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[EFloOnline.Model.Constants.smtpport]));

if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[EFloOnline.Model.Constants.smtpUseCredentials] == "true")
{
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[EFloOnline.Model.Constants.smtpusername], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[EFloOnline.Model.Constants.smtppassword], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[EFloOnline.Model.Constants.smtp]);
}
else
{
    smtp.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    if (SendTo.Count == 0)
    {
        SendTo.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[EFloOnline.Model.Constants.ToMail]);
    }

    foreach (string recipientemail in SendTo)
    {
        oEmail.To.Add(recipientemail);
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(oEmail);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        oEmail.To.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code and configuration look correct.

Are you sure you have put the system.net/mailSettings element in the web.config in the root directory of your web site?

A common mistake is to put such settings in the web.config in the Views folder.

Incidentally, the `MailMessage` class implements `IDisposable`, as does the `SmtpClient` class from .NET 4.  So you should be enclosing both in `using` blocks.

Comment: I have added smpt configuration in root web.config not view one! do i have to put setting in web.config???

Answer (score 0):

- Not sure if smtp.live.com is still valid http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app does not seem to list it
- I would check if Port 25 is Blocked if Port 25 is blocked, try Port 587 (Might have to enable SSL for 587)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post about doing this.
http://www.bgsoftfactory.net/5-steps-to-send-email-with-mvcmailer-from-an-mvc-4-0-application/

I took the easier way, using MVCMailer. Even if sending email from MVC is quite easy, it's a little more complicated to make it nice, while MVCMailer allow to use razor templates to format the body of your email.

You may save yourself some time by using MVCMailer.

Answer (score 0):

you missing smptClient.Send(mailMessage); at the end of your code

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add("yourEmail@hotmail.co.uk");
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("myEmail@hotmail.co.uk");
mailMessage.Subject = "testing 2 ";
mailMessage.Body = "Hello Mr. Aderson";
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
//this what you miss
    smptClient.Send(mailMessage);
//
```